# Button Image show

Tags: javascript, function

This is my html

```
        <img src="images/first.jpg" id="picture1" style="display:none;">
        <img src="images/second.jpg" id="picture2" style="display:none;">
        <img src="images/third.jpg" id="picture3" style="display:none;">


      <button class="picture1" onclick="picture()">Picture1</button>
      <button class="picture2" onclick="picture2()">Picture2</button>
      <button class="picture3" onclick="picture3()">Picture3</button>
```

This is my js

```
function picture(){
      document.getElementById('picture1').src;
      document.getElementById('picture1').style.display='block';

      }
      function picture2(){
             document.getElementById('picture2').src;
             document.getElementById('picture2').style.display='block';

             }

             function picture3(){
                    document.getElementById('picture3').src;
                    document.getElementById('picture3').style.display='block';

                    }
```

So how can i make if i click one button that picture to appear and when i click another button the picture from the first button to disappear and the picture from the current clicked button to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily by having just one function as shown below. You can initially have the image hidden, and have it shown by pressing the button. Pass the value through the function parameter, and just switch the values depending on the button that should show the respective picture.

```js
function picture(num){
  document.getElementById('picture').style.display = 'block';
  switch(num) {
    case 1: document.getElementById('picture').src = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/150/150"; break;
    case 2: document.getElementById('picture').src = "https://picsum.photos/id/238/150/150"; break;
    case 3: document.getElementById('picture').src = "https://picsum.photos/id/239/150/150"; break;
    default: document.getElementById('picture').src = "https://picsum.photos/id/237/150/150"; break;
  }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Image</h2>
<img src="" width="150" height="150" id="picture" style="display: none;">
<br />
<button onclick="picture(1)">picture 1</button>
<button onclick="picture(2)">picture 2</button>
<button onclick="picture(3)">picture 3</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function picture(){
      document.getElementById('picture1').src;
      document.getElementById('picture1').style.display='block';
      document.getElementById('picture2').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('picture3').style.display='none';

      }
      function picture2(){
             document.getElementById('picture2').src;
             document.getElementById('picture2').style.display='block';
             document.getElementById('picture1').style.display='none';
             document.getElementById('picture3').style.display='none';

             }

             function picture3(){
                    document.getElementById('picture3').src;
                    document.getElementById('picture3').style.display='block';
                    document.getElementById('picture1').style.display='none';
                    document.getElementById('picture2').style.display='none';
                    };
```

```html
<img src="images/first.jpg" id="picture1" style="display:none;">
        <img src="images/second.jpg" id="picture2" style="display:none;">
        <img src="images/third.jpg" id="picture3" style="display:none;">


      <button class="picture1" onclick="picture()">Picture1</button>
      <button class="picture2" onclick="picture2()">Picture2</button>
      <button class="picture3" onclick="picture3()">Picture3</button>
```